Start asynchronous, service-dependent task from ASP.NET Core web method
I want to asynchronously launch some operation from within an ASP.NET Core API controller's web method (the operation is fire-and-forget).
Tricky part is, this operation relies on services from the DI service provider, including scoped or transient ones.
Is it as simple as
Task.Run(() => MyFireAndForgetOperation(serviceScopeFactory))

or is there something more I need to watch out for?

But scoped/transient service will dispose before your task ends. You can only rely on singleton service.
